# How to set a namespace to the instance of stdClass?

Tags: php, type-conversion, stdclass

I need to change the type of object from stdClass to "myClass", so like does PDO::fetch_object("myClass");

```
$inc = new stdClass;
$inc = funct_for_set_type_of_object("myClass"); // here the function to do 
                                                // namespace conversion
echo get_class($inc);
```

Expected result:`myClass`

I need function like above: "get_class", but with behaviour like "set_class".

Comment: And the problem/question is ... ?

Comment: as you can see in a code, i dunno what function name to do this.

Comment: What not understandable is there?

Comment: You haven't seen the code above? I've create instance of stdClass, after, i needs to change its namespace. It is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need function like above: "get_class", but with behaviour like "set_class".

I short: There is no class cast in PHP, but I don't know, if this is *really* your problem

```
$x = $pdo->fetchObject($classname);
```

As far as I can see there is no need for a class cast anymore, if you provide the right class name.

[PDOStatement::fetchObject()](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetchobject)

Comment: Where you seen that i've get any data from PDO?

Comment: _There is no class cast in PHP_
It is all. Thanks for no help.